# Node.js MySql query returns undefined rows object

Tags: mysql, node.js

Given the following case:

```
 connection.query('SELECT * from packages WHERE AQUIRED="'+req.session.user+'" AND PROCCESSED=0 ORDER BY PACKAGEID LIMIT 1 ', function(err, resultRow) {
    console.log( 'rows '+resultRow.toString() ); // by here resultRow is not defined and err is null
 }
```

Database is connected, `req.session.user` is not an empty string and there are rows in the database table that match this query.

How can it happen that `err` is `null`, but `resultRow` is also not defined? If anything, `resultRow` should be empty object.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure about the `resultRow1` in your example?

Comment: Why are you using `resultRow1` if you've defined `resultRow`  as the variable for results in the callback funciton?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jso mentioned about, there is a typo in the variable name inside the callback. I believe SQL in Node.js returns an array of objects, so if you try something like

```
console.log( 'rows '+resultRow[0].toString() );
```

it should work. Of course it is always a good idea to add in error checking and such, like the size of the array. Good luck mate!